# Committee of size k out of n couples selected, probability of exactly j couples in it.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> An organization with 2n people consists of n married couples. A committee of size k is
>   selected, with all possibilities equally likely. Find the probability that there are exactly j married couples within the committee. (Introduction to Probability, Blitzstein and Nwang, p.36)

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: If there are no restrictions, number of committees possible is $\binom{2n}{k}$. If $k>2j$, how many ways to choose the $j$ couples, and how many ways to choose remaining $k-2j$ members such that you won't accidentally choose another pair of couple?

Comment: @jh4 Okay, so I would say there are $\prod_{i=1}^{i=j} \binom{k-2(i-1)}{2} \binom{n}{j}$ ways to choose the j couples and $\prod_{i=1}^{i=k-2j} \binom{(2n-2j) - 2(i-1)}{1}$ ways to choose the rest?

Comment: @Dominik: Your first expression is wrong: there are just $\binom{n}j$ ways to choose the $j$ couples. Your second expression is right, but it can be simplified greatly. The simplification isn’t terribly obvious, but it falls out naturally from a different way of looking at choosing the rest. Would you like to think about it further, or should I post an answer?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hey, you are coming right in time! I'm actually surprised that at least the second expression is right. I wrapped my head around it for too long now, so I would greatly appreciate an answer.

Comment: Okay; let me know if anything in it isn’t clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are $\binom{n}j$ ways to choose $j$ couples. That leaves $n-j$ couples, from which you have to choose $k-2j$ people, no two of whom are a couple. The slick way to do this is to choose $k-2j$ of the remaining $n-j$ couples, which you can do in $\binom{n-j}{k-2j}$ ways, and then choose one of the two members of each of those couples, which you can do in $2^{k-2j}$ ways. Thus, you can form

$$\binom{n}j\binom{n-j}{k-2j}2^{k-2j}$$

committees of size $k$ containing exactly $j$ couples. Dividing this by $\binom{2n}k$ of course gives the desired probability.

Comment: I understand the second part of first choosing from which couple the remaining $k-2j$ people come from, and then choosing which partner of the couple it is. What I don't understand is which the first part is $\binom{n}{j}$. For instance, I would think that if I wanna have $j=2$ couples, I have $\binom{k}{2}$ choices for the first couple and $\binom{k-2}{2}$ for the second couple in my committee of size k. Then, the identity of those two couples can be chosen in $\binom{n}{2}$ different ways.

Comment: @Dominik: But you don’t have $\binom{k}2$ choices for the first couple. If you think of picking the couples one person at a time, you have $2n$ ways to pick the first person, but then the second person must be the first person’s spouse; $2n-2$ ways to pick the third person, but then the fourth person must be the third person’s spouse; and so on. This gives you the product $$(2n)(2n-2)(2n-4)\ldots(2n-2j+2)\;,$$ but it overcounts: each of the $j$ couples could have been chosen in $2$ ways, so you have to divide by $2^j$, and the $j$ couples could have been chosen in $j!$ orders, so you have ...

Comment: ... to divide by $j!$. And when you’ve made those corrections, the whole thing simplifies to $\binom{n}j$. But it’s much easier to note that you have $n$ couples, and you want $j$ of them, so there are $\binom{n}j$ ways to choose the couples to be included on your committee.

Comment: Oddly, I find the complicated ways you described easier to understand. Somehow, I'm feeling forced to think in terms of choosing from the total population $2n$, instead of the couples $n$.

Comment: @Dominik: In such problems it often pays to think about different possible ways to choose whatever is being chosen, because one way often leads more easily to a nice formula. Here, for instance, it really helps to see that for both parts of the committee you can think directly in terms of couples, rather than individuals: for the first part you want both members of the couple, and for the second you want just one, but in both parts thinking in terms of couples gets you away from complicated products.

Comment: Reconsidering the problem thinking in terms of couples, it's actually straightforward. Thank you also for providing some piece of "methodological" advice. That really helps.

Comment: @Dominik: You’re welcome.