# Subproblem of "Committee of size k out of n couples selected, probability of exactly j couples in it"

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem is stated as:

> An organization with 2n people consists of n married couples. A
> committee of size k is selected, with all possibilities equally
> likely. Find the probability that there are exactly j married couples
> within the committee. (Introduction to Probability, Blitzstein and
> Nwang, p.36)

There already is a pretty detailed answer to it here: [Committee of size k out of n couples selected, probability of exactly j couples in it.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056151/committee-of-size-k-out-of-n-couples-selected-probability-of-exactly-j-couples)

However, in the answer I don't understand how the part about choosing one of two members of the remaining couple works.

For clarification, the way to choose j couples on the committee is ${n \choose j}$, then filling in the rest of the committee is done by choosing ${n-j \choose k - 2j}$ couples, then choosing ${2^{k - 2j}}$ individuals from those couples (thereby avoiding couples in the rest of the committee).

What trips me is the ${2^{k-2j}}$ part. How does that select individuals from ${n-j \choose k-2j}$?

I know that ${2^n}$ gives me all subsets of n, but if n are the remaining individuals, (${k-2j}$), then I don't see how those subsets won't include couples from that group. I think I'm getting confused by first thinking in couples, then trying to think in individuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After choosing $j$ complete couples for the committee, there are $n-j$ couples remaining, from which $k-2j$ individuals must be chosen in such a way that no two individuals come from the same couple.

One way to handle this is to choose $k-2j$ of the $n-j$ remaining couples (there are ${n-j}\choose {k-2j}$ ways to do this), and then from each of these chosen couples choose one person. So you have two choices (couple member 1 or couple member 2) from each of these $k-2j$ couples, which explains the factor of $2^{k-2j}$.

Comment: Aha! So ${2^{k-2j}}$ is basically about counting permutations with replacement? As in, if we lived in a universe where "couple" meant three beings, this specific part of the equation would be: ${3^{k-3j}}$? because you could choose couple member 1, 2, or 3 from ${k-3j}$ couples?