# Introduction of probability's Chapter 1, question 37

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

An organization with 2n people consists of n married couples. A committee of size k is
selected, with all possibilities equally likely. Find the probability that there are exactly j married couples within the committee.

I have no idea how to do this question. I saw an exact post but the answer is the same as the solution, confusing. The post was [Committee of size k out of n couples selected, probability of exactly j couples in it.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056151/committee-of-size-k-out-of-n-couples-selected-probability-of-exactly-j-couples)

and the solution was  $\Large\frac{{N \choose j} \times {N-j \choose K-2j} \times 2^{K-2j}}{2N \choose K}$

I tried to understand the solution by giving an small value to the question. The question now is "There are 10 people and there are 5 couples. A committee of size 6 is selected. Find the probability that there are exactly 2 couples within the committee."

So for the denominator, $10 \choose 6$ makes sense.

We need exactly 2 couples, so within the present 5 couples, $5 \choose 2$ still makes sense so far which is the $N\choose k$ in the solution.

The part $ N-j \choose {k-2j}$, which is $4\choose 1$ in my example, is where I got lost.

Is 4 representing the unselected couples?

And what does the $2^{K-2j}$ mean?

Comment: You have garbled the formula. The first term in the numerator should be $\binom{N}{j}$ The full formula  has been clearly explained in the link you have given.

Comment: You're totally right. Fixed it